# Where do i find obs studio after i install it?

Tags: command-line

Iv'e been trying to install obs studio for some time now and it says its installed, but i cant find it anywhere.I have tried to update FFmpeg and bunch of other things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply running `obs` should bring it up.

Otherwise, run `apropos obs` or `apropos obs studio` to find how to invoke it.